# Make a shape move towards mouse in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, shapes

Here is my code:

```
void Ant::Update(float dt, sf::RenderWindow& window) {
// calculate difference between mouse pos and ant pos
float x = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
float y = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;

if (this->pos.x + radius > x) {
    this->pos.x -= speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.y + radius > y) {
    this->pos.y -= speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.x + radius < x) {
    this->pos.x += speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.y + radius < y) {
    this->pos.y += speed * dt;
}

this->antCircle.setPosition(this->pos.x, this->pos.y);
}
```

So I want a circle to smoothly (like rotate) to face the computer mouse. Right now, it doesn't circularly rotate to move towards the mouse; it just changes direction abruptly to follow the mouse. I know this involves some trig but I'm hoping someone can help work through this with me. Thank you!

EDIT 1:
I tried this

```
void Ant::Update(float dt, sf::RenderWindow& window) {
// calculate difference between mouse pos and ant pos
float x = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
float y = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;

if (this->stackSpeed.x > 3) {
    this->stackSpeed.x = 0;
}
if (this->stackSpeed.y > 3) {
    this->stackSpeed.y = 0;
}

if (this->pos.x + radius > x) {
    //this->pos.x -= speed * dt;
    this->stackSpeed.x -= speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.y + radius > y) {
    //this->pos.y -= speed * dt;
    this->stackSpeed.y -= speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.x + radius < x) {
    //this->pos.x += speed * dt;
    this->stackSpeed.x += speed * dt;
}
if (this->pos.y + radius < y) {
    //this->pos.y += speed * dt;
    this->stackSpeed.y += speed * dt;
}

this->pos.x += this->stackSpeed.x;
this->pos.y += this->stackSpeed.y;

this->antCircle.setPosition(this->pos.x, this->pos.y);
```

}

No luck. This just makes the ball vibrate all over the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the distance formula sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2):

```
void Ant::Update(float dt, sf::RenderWindow& window) {
// calculate difference between mouse pos and ant pos
float x = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
float y = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;

float xDist = x - (this->pos.x + radius);
float yDist = y - (this->pos.y + radius);
float dist = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

if (dist > 1) {
    this->pos.x += xDist * dt * speed;
    this->pos.y += yDist * dt * speed;
}

this->antCircle.setPosition(this->pos.x, this->pos.y);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve a more smooth movement is to let the circle have it's own speed, and then modify that speed depending on the position.

```
void Ant::Update(float dt, sf::RenderWindow& window) {

    // calculate difference between mouse pos and ant pos
    float x = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
    float y = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
    
    if (this->pos.x + radius > x) {
        this->speed.x -= force * dt;
    }
    if (this->pos.y + radius > y) {
        this->speed.y -= force * dt;
    }
    if (this->pos.x + radius < x) {
        this->speed.x += force * dt;
    }
    if (this->pos.y + radius < y) {
        this->speed.y += force * dt;
    }

    this->pos.x += this->speed.x;
    this->pos.y += this->speed.y;
    
    this->antCircle.setPosition(this->pos.x, this->pos.y);
}
```

You might also want to make sure that the speed doesn't get too big. Give it a maximum value that it's not allowed to exceed.
Or use some proper physics and math to do more realistic calculations.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're saying. You are changing the speed rather than the position...

Comment: @jbcallv Well, both really. First update the speed. Then use the speed to update the position. I omitted updating `pos.x` and `pos.y` cause I thought that would be obvious from the example.

Comment: Also poor choice of variable names... a member named speed, and a global named speed.

Comment: Just FYI, it's not required to use `this->` when refering to class members inside a member function.

Comment: "a member named speed, and a global..." I'm new to C++. Which variables are you referring to? The one I have called speed or the 2D vector you added called speed? Thanks for letting me know about this->

Comment: @jbcallv I added a member named speed and renamed the global to force for clarity. Use the force to update the speed, use the speed to update the position.

Comment: This way, when the force changes direction, it still take a while for the speed to go from positive to negative (or the other way around), so you get a smooth transition.

Comment: @jbcallv Just saw your edit. If the ball is vibrating all over then the force is way to high. You need to adjust it down. If the stackspeed max is 3, force should probably be around 0.1 or maybe even less. Plus you need to limit the speed to not go below `-3` as well since the speed can be both positive and negative. Come on man, you need to do some of the thinking yourself here.